# WP: Override Search Widget

Tags: php, wordpress

i Put search widget in my website (default Wordpress 3.0.4). The default output will be

```
<form action="http://alessandro.host/" id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
    <div><label for="s" class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit">
    </div>
</form>
```

now i want to override that to make the output will be like this

```
<form action="http://alessandro.host/" id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

Notice there is no `label` and `send button`

how i can make it?

Comment: You want to know where the template is to edit it?

Comment: i made a file with name search.php, then in there where will be the function running. hopefully i want to not edit the core file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to rename your search.php to searchform.php and place it in your theme folder. Wordpress first checks the file in current theme folder and if not found then it displays the default template.

I think you need [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) and [this](http://wpengineer.com/1716/wordpress-searchform-template-tag-or-template/).

It describes both ways, adding your template or override the basic search form/criteria.

Happy Coding